# Idiomatic way to slice a Perl array by value rather than index

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

I have a piece of code that extracts a slice from one of two large arrays of sorted integers, representing stopping points in the program's workflow. I'll include one of the two here.

The basic idea is that I'm trying to slice a work range out of this large array as a starting point for this program to work on. `$min` is pulled from the task object, representing the current progress of the task. `$limit` is an optional user override, defaulting to `-1` (which is ignored).

Currently, I'm using the `firstidx` function from the `List::MoreUtils` CPAN module to retrieve the indices for the start and finish, and then I'm using them to slice the `@steps` array in the usual way. Is there a faster and/or more idiomatic way of doing this? Particularly, is there a good way to do it by directly using the `$min` and `$limit` values (with another codepath for the `$limit == -1` case)?

Here's the code:

```
my @steps = (
    0, 1, 5, 10,
    20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
    200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,
    1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000,
    2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000,
    6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000,
    11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 17500, 20000,
    25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000,
    60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000
);
my $min_index = firstidx { $_ > $min } @steps;
my $max_index;
if ($limit == -1) {
    $max_index = @steps - 1;
} else {
    $max_index = firstidx { $_ >= $limit } @steps;
}
my @steps_todo = @steps[ $min_index .. $max_index ];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the start/end conditions? Start at 10 when `$min` is 5. End at 40 when `$limit` is 31?

Comment: @clamp Yes, that's right. `@steps_todo` is a list of maximum _p_ values for a prime sieve program, the premise being that I check the factor removal rate at each step to determine whether it's worthwhile to continue. Since the `$min` step (the current progress) has already been reached, it's skipped. It was seen as too confusing to my workflow to allow custom steps (like 31), so it rounds up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple foreach loop.  The flow control keywords control when you start or stop consuming the `@steps` array.

I changed the no-limit case to be a defined check since that's more efficient.

This is not the most efficient possible algorithm but it's a simple idomatic way of solving it.

```perl
use diagnostics; # Very verbose warnings
($min, $max, @out) = (1000, 9999);

@steps = (
    0, 1, 5, 10,
    20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
    200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,
    1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000,
    2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000,
    6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000,
    11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 17500, 20000,
    25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000,
    60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000
);


foreach (@steps) {
    next if $_ < $min;
    last if defined $max and $_ > $max;
    push @out, $_;
}


print "@out";

## output
## 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000
```

This is also a possible use case for the flip flop operator, `..`.  It looks like the list range operator but in scalar context it's flip flop.  Think of it as like the `cmp` tristate operator but for arbitrary expressions.  It returns a value that defines a range from "this" to "that".  Call it a flapper.  Look at this sample.  See the [perlop Range Operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) section for more info.  The operands can be anything that returns a boolean.

```perl
use Data::Dump qw/pp/;
($min, $max) = (1000, 9999);
foreach (@steps) {
    my $x = ($_ >= $min .. $_ < $max);
    printf "%-9s %s\n", $_, pp $x;
}

## Output
0         ""
1         ""
5         ""
10        ""
20        ""
30        ""
40        ""
50        ""
60        ""
70        ""
80        ""
90        ""
100       ""
200       ""
300       ""
400       ""
500       ""
600       ""
700       ""
800       ""
900       ""
1000      "1E0"
1200      "1E0"
1400      "1E0"
1600      "1E0"
1800      "1E0"
2000      "1E0"
2500      "1E0"
3000      "1E0"
3500      "1E0"
4000      "1E0"
4500      "1E0"
5000      "1E0"
6000      "1E0"
7000      "1E0"
8000      "1E0"
9000      "1E0"
10000     1
11000     2
12000     3
13000     4
14000     5
15000     6
17500     7
20000     8
25000     9
30000     10
35000     11
40000     12
45000     13
50000     14
60000     15
70000     16
80000     17
90000     18
100000    19
```

Notice the ones that return "1E0" because those values trigger a reset in the flip flop.  In a real loop that transition point is where it would terminate.  You can play with the arguments to pick what set of values get "", "1E0", or the sequence number and act accordingly.

This version gives the sequence number to the wanted value and then starts the "E0" reset values beyond.

```
($_ >= $min .. $_ > $max);

...
800       ""
900       ""
1000      1
1200      2
...
8000      15
9000      16
10000     "17E0"
11000     "1E0"
12000     "1E0"
...
```

Here's how you would solve it using flip flop.  The advantage of this way is that the lower bound condition is no longer evaluated once it's reached.  The major downside is that it's super cryptic and probably won't be understandable to non-Perl programmers.  But this is as compact and efficient as it can get.

```perl
foreach (@steps) {
    ($_ >= $min .. ($_ > $max and last)) or next;
    push @out, $_;
}

print "@out\n";
## 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000
```

While the left flapper is false, the whole expression is false and we go to the next item.  When the left flapper becomes true, the whole expression is now true and we go on and start checking the right flapper.  While the right flapper is false (the whole expression is still true), we go on to save the item in `@out`.  When the right flapper becomes true, we terminate the loop. (This is also where it would reset back to false.)

One more edit. :)

If there is no max, here's a good way to do it.

```perl
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#steps; $i++) {
    next unless $steps[$i] >= $min;
    @out = @steps[$i .. $#steps];
    # Or, if you don't need the original array anymore you can consume it 
    # and be a bit more efficient and save memory
    # @out = splice @steps, $i;
    last;

}
```

Great question!

Comment: Your output does not match the expected one. According to the question with input of `1000, 9999`  output should start with `1200` and end with `10000`.  In your first example move the `push` up one line.

Comment: @clamp Ah, I didn't realize that.  This change will get your values. `foreach (@steps) { (($_ > $min ) .. ($_ >= $max and (push(@out, $_), last))) or next; push @out, $_;} print "@out\n";` --> `1200 1400 1600 1800 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000`

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily idiomatic or performant, but you could construct an iterator:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw( firstidx );

sub work_steps {
    my ($steps, $min, $max) = @_;

    my $start = firstidx { $_ > $min } @$steps;
    return sub {} if $start == -1;

    my $end;

    if ($max != -1) {
        $end = firstidx { $_ >= $max } @$steps;
        return sub {} if $end == -1;
    }
    else {
        $end = $#$steps;
    }

    return sub {} if $start > $end;

    my $k = $start;

    return sub {
        return unless ($k >= $start) && ($k <= $end);
        return $steps->[$k++];
    }
}

sub main {
    my @steps = (
        0, 1, 5, 10,
        20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
        200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,
        1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000,
        2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000,
        6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000,
        11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 17500, 20000,
        25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000,
        60000, 70000, 80000, 90000, 100000
    );

    my $it = work_steps(\@steps, 222, 9300);

    while (my $step = $it->()) {
        say $step;
    }
}

main();
```

This avoids the construction of an extra array so reduces memory pressure. This may matter if the lists you are processing are large enough.

You can pass around the iterator instead of the range. This might make programs easier to read.

On the other hand, the extra work done on each iteration may also matter.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way would be to use grep to select the range.  That has the disadvantage that it scans the entire array, which might be a performance point if the array is large and the grep is executed often.

Since the list is sorted, a possibility for performance (but certainly no shorter or simpler) is to use the binary search functions from List::MoreUtils to find the bounds of the range.